# Tensorflow: sess.run(x) not working. InvalidArgumentError: Cannot assign a device for operation 'MatMul': Operation was assigned to /device:GPU:1

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm using python 3.6(Anaconda) on windows-64bit PC. TensorFlow version that I'm using is TensorFlow-1.2.1. I'm running following simple code in my PC.

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session()
x1 = tf.constant(5)
x2 = tf.constant(6)

# runs result
print(sess.run(x1))
```

It is giving me following error.:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-64-f7e8ea564f81>", line 7, in <module>
print(sess.run(x1))

File "C:\Users\POPEYE.SAILOR\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 789, in run
run_metadata_ptr)

File "C:\Users\POPEYE.SAILOR\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 997, in _run
feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)

File "C:\Users\POPEYE.SAILOR\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1132, in _do_run
target_list, options, run_metadata)

File "C:\Users\POPEYE.SAILOR\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1152, in _do_call
raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)

InvalidArgumentError: Cannot assign a device for operation 'MatMul': Operation was explicitly assigned to /device:GPU:1 but available devices are [ /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0 ]. Make sure the device specification refers to a valid device.
[[Node: MatMul = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false, _device="/device:GPU:1"](Const_2, Const_3)]]

Caused by op 'MatMul', defined at:
File "C:\Users\POPEYE.SAILOR\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 227, in <module>
main()
File "C:\Users\POPEYE.SAILOR\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 223, in main
kernel.start()
File "C:\Users\POPEYE.SAILOR\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 474, in start
ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
File "C:\Users\POPEYE.SAILOR\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\ioloop.py", line 177, in start
super(ZMQIOLoop, self).start()
File "C:\Users\POPEYE.SAILOR\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 887, in start
handler_func(fd_obj, events)
File "C:\Users\POPEYE.SAILOR\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py", line 275, in null_wrapper
return fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\POPEYE.SAILOR\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 440, in _handle_events
self._handle_recv()
File "C:\Users\POPEYE.SAILOR\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 472, in _handle_recv
self._run_callback(callback, msg)
File "C:\Users\POPEYE.SAILOR\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 414, in _run_callback
callback(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\POPEYE.SAILOR\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py", line 275, in null_wrapper
return fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\POPEYE.SAILOR\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 276, in dispatcher
return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
File "C:\Users\POPEYE.SAILOR\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 228, in dispatch_shell
handler(stream, idents, msg)
File "C:\Users\POPEYE.SAILOR\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 390, in execute_request
user_expressions, allow_stdin)
File "C:\Users\POPEYE.SAILOR\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 196, in do_execute
res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
File "C:\Users\POPEYE.SAILOR\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\zmqshell.py", line 501, in run_cell
return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\POPEYE.SAILOR\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2717, in run_cell
interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
File "C:\Users\POPEYE.SAILOR\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2821, in run_ast_nodes
if self.run_code(code, result):
File "C:\Users\POPEYE.SAILOR\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
File "<ipython-input-18-02c5e13ac58a>", line 5, in <module>
product = tf.matmul(matrix1, matrix2)
File "C:\Users\POPEYE.SAILOR\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py", line 1816, in matmul
a, b, transpose_a=transpose_a, transpose_b=transpose_b, name=name)
File "C:\Users\POPEYE.SAILOR\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py", line 1217, in _mat_mul
transpose_b=transpose_b, name=name)
File "C:\Users\POPEYE.SAILOR\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 767, in apply_op
op_def=op_def)
File "C:\Users\POPEYE.SAILOR\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2506, in create_op
original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
File "C:\Users\POPEYE.SAILOR\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1269, in __init__
self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Cannot assign a device for operation 'MatMul': Operation was explicitly assigned to /device:GPU:1 but available devices are [ /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0 ]. Make sure the device specification refers to a valid device.
[[Node: MatMul = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false, _device="/device:GPU:1"](Const_2, Const_3)]]
```

Prior to this it was running just fine. I could run these codes but suddenly is has started showing the above error. I have not made any changes in anaconda environment nor have installed any other package.

Comment: Did you paste your complete code? I don't see you calling MatMul OP anywhere in this code. It would help if you can paste your complete code here.
Your code would just print the value 5.

Comment: Please check out how to [create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the error you show does not match the code you posted.